# How to call EnumSystemLocales in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi, internationalization, globalization, delphi-5

i am trying to call [`EnumSystemLocales`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317828%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Delphi. [For example:](http://www.podgoretsky.com/ftp/Docs/Delphi/D5/dg/intapps.html)

```
{ Called for each supported locale. }
function LocalesCallback(Name: PChar): BOOL; stdcall;
begin
   OutputDebugString(Name);
   Result := Bool(1); //True
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   EnumSystemLocales(@LocalesCallback, LCID_SUPPORTED);
end;
```

The problem is that the callback is only being called once.

**Note:** `EnumSystemLocales` *is* returning true, indicating success.

The remarks of `EnumSystemLocales` says that my callback must return **true** to continue enumerating (or more correctly, must not return **false** to continue enumerating):

> The function enumerates locales by passing locale identifiers, one at
>   a time, to the specified application-defined callback function. This
>   continues until all of the installed or supported locale identifiers
>   have been passed to the callback function or the callback function
>   returns FALSE.

On the [documentation of the callback function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317822%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumLocalesProc(
  __in  LPTSTR lpLocaleString
);
```

a commenter has come across a problem with the definition of "not false":

> This function must return 1, not (DWORD) -1 to continue processing

This makes me think that delphi's definition of

```
True: BOOL;
```

is different than Window's. (That's why i tried a return value of `BOOL(1)` - which still fails).

Next i wonder if it's not even supposed to be `stdcall`.

Either way, can someone suggest how, in Delpi, to call `EnumSystemLocales`?

---

**Edit**: Also tried:

- `Result := BOOL(-1);`
- `Result := BOOL($FFFFFFFF);`
- `Result := BOOL(1);`
- `Result := True;`

Comment: The problem seems to be focused on the manner to write the callback function rather than calling EnumSystemLocales. Am I right?

Comment: @menjaraz It very well might be - but i don't want to discount any possiblity.

Comment: It may also have to do with Windows, I use Delphi XE and encounter all the issues mentionned. Any similar feedback ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try declarating the `LocalesCallback` function like this

```
function LocalesCallback(Name: PChar): Integer; stdcall;
```

check this sample

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils;

function LocalesCallback(Name: PChar): Integer; stdcall;
begin
   Writeln(Name);
   Result := 1;
end;

begin
  try
    EnumSystemLocales(@LocalesCallback, LCID_SUPPORTED);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: @menjaraz - It's a workaround for missing/incompatible data type in the language. See http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=72852

Comment: @menjaraz, yes it is a workaround, and rather ugly for my taste. See my answer for background details.

Comment: Funny, FPC had similar problems in spring with (mostly) GTK. Now has boolean8/16/32.

Comment: Sorry for the late accept; i upvoted and commented, but forgot the most important step.

Answer (score 4):

This problem happens due WinAPI bug, observed in Windows version 5.1
WinNls EnumXXX function family (and, according to the comments, probably several others) is only recognizing exactly `(BOOL)1` as `(BOOL)TRUE` and will stop enumeration if callback returns any other `returnValue != (BOOL)FALSE`.

Here is a most semantic workaround i figured out:

```
  LongWord(Result) := LongWord(True);     // WINBUG: WinNls functions will continue
                                          // enumeration only if exactly 1 was returned
                                          // from the callback
```

Comment: Problem is that there's so many booleans to choose from (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/12/22/329884.aspx)

Comment: @IanBoyd, not really, our [primary documentation source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317822%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) clearly states which type we (client developers) must use. Problem is what NLS subsytem doesnt follow its own rules. And what mr. Chen unwillingly confirms in his diary - is what MS project managers failed to coordinate common style amongst teams, allowing described *type zoo* to spread over code-base.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using `BOOL` type for callback function result, use this:

```
function LocalesCallback(Name: PChar): BOOL; stdcall;
begin
   OutputDebugString(Name);
   LongWord(Result) := 1;
end;
```

because `Bool(1) = $FFFFFFFF`.

Comment: Is that a workaround or is there a compiler issue on casting to BOOL type ?

Comment: AFAIK in old C the type BOOL was Integer type, and true = !false; since false = 0, that means true = not 0 = $FFFFFFFF (assuming sizeof(bool) = 4). That is my guess, I may be wrong.

Comment: C has no boolean type till C99.  INT (Integers) can be tested without == though, and then the semantic you name are valid (false=0 true =!false).  But APIs have different conventions. GTK GBoolean is the same. They are actually closer to the Pascal boolean type, but that exists in Delphi as 8 bits variant only.

Comment: @Serg i wasn't really insisting on using `BOOL`. The Win32 API says `BOOL` (which it also says is `typedef int BOOL;`). i just assumed Delphi's `BOOL` (which is `Windows.BOOL = LongBool;`) was compatible with Window's `BOOL`.